# Does Safari Inspector allow server side Nodejs debugging?

Tags: node.js, safari-web-inspector

I can use Chrome to connect to a web socket on a remote system invoked with `node --inspect-brk index.js`.

Does Safari offer similar capabilities?  I looked around in the Inspector developer tools, however found no place to assign the WebSocket IP and port.

Thanks